# Why can't I call UIComponent.setValueExpression()?

Tags: java, jsf, compiler-errors

I have received a project with many lines like the following ones:

```
HtmlOutputText content = new HtmlOutputText();
ValueBinding vb = dashBoardBean.getApplication()
    .createValueBinding(columnas[cont][1]);
content.setValueBinding("value", vb);
```

Eclipse, with Java 5, marks them as deprecated (both class `ValueBinding`and the method `setValueBinding`).

So I looked the [API for `HtmlCommandLink.setValueBinding()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponentBase.html#setValueBinding%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.el.ValueBinding%29) (it actually is at UIComponentBase) and found this:

**Deprecated.** *This has been replaced by [UIComponent.setValueExpression(java.lang.String, javax.el.ValueExpression)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setValueExpression%28java.lang.String,%20javax.el.ValueExpression%29).*

So I changed the last line code to the following:

```
content.setValueExpression("value", null);
```

But now I get a compiler error.

I also tried:

```
UIComponent uic;
uic.setValueExpression("", null);
```

And get the same error:

```
The type javax.el.ValueExpression cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from
```

required .class files

What's the meaning of that error? How can I solve it?

Comment: It means that its generating a `<h:outputText value="" />` and in second chance is doing `<h:outputText ="" />`

Comment: @ Luiggi Mendoza The error is a compiler-error. Underlined in red color by Eclipse. I can't execute the code.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza I'm checking it...

Comment: `jsf-facelets.jar` says it's 1.1, albeit I also have a file called `myfaces-api-1.2.2.jar`. I think the Flintstones used a newer version than me.

Comment: Well then @BillyBobBain has the right answer. Next time you post a JSF question please write the version you're using :)

Comment: I didn't know it could be related to the version (in fact, I didn't even know which version the project was using) until I read these comments. Muchas gracias @Luiggi Mendoza :-)

Comment: De nada no hay problema, but next time try to use english only:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the JSF 1.2 (or greater) jars on your classpath.